# Is there a way to check the color of a nested component in jetpack compose using assertions?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-jetpack-compose, android-testing, android-jetpack

I need to check when the color of a nested composable changes if the parent composable is on error state. Let's say that there is a fixed label text describing the error state of the parent composable(text input). When the error state is on (user has typed less that 5 characters) the color of that label changes to a specific color from my color resources. How can I test that the color of a description has changed to that specific color?